# Demo Application using Executor Framework

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, executorservice

I am very new to the executor framework,so Please clear my doubts on the executor code i have mentioned below

Task Requirement:

1)I have (10-20k) records in the arraylist which i will assign to the fixed thread pool.
2) I will execute all the task as in the code.
3)I want each thread will call the webservice(rest/soap)
4)After getting the response it will write the response in the same file(lets say A).

I have done the dummy code below ,I know I need validation and all but I want to know what precaution I need to have on thread side.

Question:
What methods should be synchronized?
What I should so more (I will handle the exception but data safety point of view)

Thanks in advance.:)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.RunnableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;

/**
 * Created by so_what on 7/20/2017.
 */

public class ExecutorDemo {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
TaskController controller=new TaskController();
        controller.startExec();
    }
}
 class TaskController
{

public TaskController(){};
    public void startExec()
    {
        //create new thread executor
        ExecutorService executorService= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        ArrayList<String>list=new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("One");list.add("Two");//few more will come from the 
        database

        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            executorService.execute(new TaskRunner(list.get(i)));
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
    }


}
class TaskRunner implements Runnable
        {
String param;

            public TaskRunner(String s) {
                this.param=s;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Thread is running "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());

                //need to call the webservice
                //after got the response ,need to wirte the response in the file
                //Question:Do this will fine?
                String response=webserviceCall("http://something.com/"+this.param); //will implement lets say dummy data
                writeToFile(response);






            }

            private void writeToFile(String response) {
                //Question :Do i need to synchronize this method?
                //here i will write the response to the flat file


            }
        }
```

Comment: As a general rule, you should synchronize anything that changes a shared state (which may include a file).

Comment: yes so writing in  a file should be synchronized other things are fine?
I just want to confirm suppose thread 1 will never go to the writeToFile method until response from webservice will not come for thread1